# Offset function using If else statement

Tags: pandas

I have a pd df and I want to create a third column"LCC_saving" based on the following conditions.

```
nvals=df['Offset_base']

for i, row in df.iterrows():

if nvals <0:
   df.at[i,'LCC_savings']=df.loc[i+row['Offset_base']]['LCC']-row['LCC']
else:
    df.at[i,'LCC_savings'] = 0

df

     Offset_base     LCC    LCC_saving 
0      1             $240       $0
1      0             $239       $0
2     -1             $244     $239-$244=-$4.77
```

I got following error message: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Can someone help the code?

Answer (score 1):

Although this kind of problems can be solved with `iterrows` and `iat` or maybe even some operations implying shift, I think the easiest, fastest and most straightforward way is to do the calculation on the underlying numpy array and assign the result to the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Offset_base': [1,0,-1], 'LCC': [240,239,244]})

a = df.to_numpy()
LCC_savings = np.zeros(len(df))
for i in range(len(df)):
    if a[i,0] < 0:
        LCC_savings[i] = a[i+a[i,0],1] - a[i,1]
df['LCC_savings'] = LCC_savings
```

Result:

```
   Offset_base  LCC  LCC_savings
0            1  240          0.0
1            0  239          0.0
2           -1  244         -5.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I modified my code yesterday as follows: if nvals.iloc[i] <0, and it also worked.